# return array value from a function in JavaScript(odoo)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, odoo

Here I want return all partners in odoo to stock picking by JavaScript:

```
get_partners: function(){
    var self = this;
    var model = new instance.web.Model('res.partner');            
    this.partners = [];
    return model.query(['id', 'name']).filter([['customer', '=', 'True']]).limit(1000).all().then(function(partners){
        _.each(partners, function(partner){
            self.partners.push(partner);
        });
     console.log(partners); // here i am getting value in array.
    });
return partners; // but here return an empty array. so i want the above array value here.
}
```

This code perfectly fetching all partners, but doesn't return the arrays. please give me suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: my code doesn't return the value, please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

**Deferred object**

The Deferred object, introduced in jQuery 1.5, is a chainable utility object created by calling the jQuery.Deferred() method. It can register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function.

```
jQuery.Deferred( [beforeStart ] )

beforeStart
Type: Function( Deferred deferred )
A function that is called just before the constructor returns.
```

A deferred object contains a promise object. Via the promise object you can specify what is to happen when the unit of work completes. You do so by setting callback functions on the promise object. I will show you how all that works later in this text.

The `jQuery.Deferred()` factory creates a new deferred object.

A Deferred object starts in the **pending** state. Any callbacks added to the object with `deferred.then()`, `deferred.always()`, `deferred.done()`, or `deferred.fail()` are queued to be executed later. Calling `deferred.resolve()` or `deferred.resolveWith()` transitions the Deferred into the resolved state and immediately executes any doneCallbacks that are set. Calling deferred.`reject()` or `deferred.rejectWith()` transitions the Deferred into the rejected state and immediately executes any failCallbacks that are set. Once the object has entered the resolved or rejected state, it stays in that state. Callbacks can still be added to the resolved or rejected Deferred — they will execute immediately.

[Click here](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to see more

Few other useful details [click](http://www.vasanthk.com/jquery-promises-and-deferred-objects/) to see it.

You should try following,

```
get_partners: function(){
    var self = this;
    var partners_def = new $.Deferred();
    var model = new instance.web.Model('res.partner');            
    var partners_arr = [];
    self.partners = [];
    model.query(['id', 'name']).filter([['customer', '=', 'True']]).limit(1000).all().then(function(partners){
        _.each(partners, function(partner){
            partners_arr.push(partner);
        });
        if(partners_arr.length > 0)
            partners_def.reject();
        else{
            self.partners = partners_arr;
            partners_def.resolve(partners_arr);
        }
        return partners_def;
    });
},
```

Comment: I don't know odoo, but `get_partners` still return undefined with that code.

Comment: `.query()` is asynchronous

Comment: Still i'm getting this error "Error: QWeb2 - template['PickingEditorWidget']: Runtime Error: Error: QWeb2 - template['PickingEditorWidget']: No enumerator given to foreach"

Comment: Can you please put alert before _each and print partners value.

Comment: Yeah, alert shows results before and after of _each. but end of the function doesn't return or print partners value. that is the problem.

Comment: working nicely, but the whole function doesn't return partners value.

Comment: but the whole function doesn't return partners value ??? what does it mean ? I didn't get you.

Comment: I updated my question with comments, please find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90402/discussion-between-jothimani-and-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd).

Comment: You need to return self.partners because partners are accessible only withing then() after that it's undefined. so you will get all the values in **self.partners**.